# Delegate to a different Jersey resource class

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I have a resource exists in an internal jar dependency (hence, I cannot change it's code):

```
@Path("doStuff")
public class ExternalResource {
    @GET
    public Response getSomething() {
    }
```

I need to create my own resource with a prefix path that is doing some checks and if they pass I want to delegate the handling to this external resource.

```
@Path("api/check")
public class MyResource {
    @GET
    public Response check() {
    }
```

Eventually, when someone calls GET /api/check/doStuff
I want my checks to be made and delegate the handling to the external resource.

How can i do something like that in Jersey?

Answer (score 0):

```
ExternalResource instance = [use here your ioc if used or new ExternalResource]

@Path("api/check")
public class MyResource {
  @GET
  public Response check() {
    return instance.getSomething();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use CDI @Inject for this purpose, but if you're ExternalResource is not an @ManagedBean then this won't work...

You can try using Jersey's @InjectParam?

```
import com.sun.jersey.api.core.InjectParam;

@Path("api/check")
public class MyResource {
    @InjectParam
    private ExternalResource extResource;
    @GET
    public Response check() {
         return extResource.getSomething()
    }
}
```